# How do I get a joint pdf using marginal pdfs in Scipy.stats?

Tags: python, scipy

Currently, I have three marginal probability density functions. I want to obtain their joint pdf, but I am unsure how to do this. It seems trivial but couldn't find an answer after googling.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

mu_0 = 0
sigma_0 = 1
loc_proposal_dist = stats.norm(loc = mu_0, scale = sigma_0)
scale_proposal_dist = stats.halfnorm() # sigma0_2 = 1 I THINK (CHECK)
df_proposal_dist = stats.randint(a=1, b=101) # df ~ Unif{1, 2, ..., 100}
joint_pdf = loc_proposal_dist * scale_proposal_dist * df_proposal_dist # Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they were independent marginals, then the joint would be their product. So, to evaluate the joint pdf you'd simple evaluate:

```
from scipy.stats import a_pdf, b_pdf, c_pdf
a_pdf(*args_a).pdf(a)*b_pdf(*args_b).pdf(b)*c_pdf(*args_c).pdf(c)
```

Oh, so for you:

```
joint_pdf = lambda loc,scale,df: loc_proposal_dist.pdf(loc) *
                                 scale_proposal_dist.pdf(scale) * 
                                 df_proposal_dist.pdf(df) # Works!
```